# Retrieving Checkbox Values from Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, checkboxes

I have a checkbox field that is populate with user choices.  I need to get the values they have selected from within a plugin. Here is my attempt. Not working.

```
    $entry  = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId, $localeId = null);
    foreach ($entry->storyCategories->options as $option) {
     var_dump($option);
    }
```

Can somebody please show me how to get these selected values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pull an array of all the options for a checkbox field by calling `getOptions()`:

```
$options = $entry->storyCategories->getOptions();
```

Each option will be an object with three properties, `label`, `value` and `selected`. To get all selected options for a field, you can loop through the options and test for the `selected` property:

```
$options = $entry->storyCategories->getOptions();
$selectedOptions = array();
foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    if ( $option->selected ) {
        $selectedOptions[] = $option;
    }
}
```

*Note that this exact code will work for Dropdown, Multi-select and Radio button fields as well.*

Comment: A quick followup question. If I were to make a change to the selected value and push it back into craft via plugin logic, am I storing a json object?

Comment: @DavidAaronMcInnis The values are technically stored in the database as a serialized array (see the column ```field_storyCategories``` in the database table ```craft_content```, but as long as you use the [EntriesService](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements#saving-elements) there's no JSON involved in the transport, no. If you have any other questions regarding updating entries/fields etc. it would probably be best to create a new question :)